# tried writing a java function in coldfusion

Tags: java, coldfusion

I tried a JAVA Function in coldfusion but i am missing something because the function is not executing properly
any clues

```
https://trycf.com/gist/353620b60c50a1bd58ced48517bb8028/acf2016?theme=monokai
```

added the java code also in the bottom

here the gist code

// cf try part

//Java function

```
public any function getAuthent(required string postData, String nonce, String endpointPath, String secretKeyBase64)
{
        var mac512  = createObject("java","javax.crypto.Mac");
        var keyBytes = binaryDecode(arguments.secretKeyBase64, "base64");
        var SecretKeySpec  = createObject("java","javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec");
        var sha256 = createObject("java", "java.security.MessageDigest");
        try {
                 var secretKey = SecretKeySpec.init(keyBytes, 'HmacSHA512');
                 mac512 = mac512.getInstance('HmacSHA512');
                 mac512.init(secretKey);
                 sha256 = sha256.getInstance("SHA-256");
         } catch (IOException e) {
             
         } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
             
         } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            
         }
         sha256.update(postData.getBytes());
         sha256.update(nonce.getBytes());
         sha256.update(endpointPath.getBytes());
         mac512.update(sha256.digest());
         return mac512.doFinal();
}
writedump(binaryEncode(getAuthent('nonce=1612466079678052','1612466079678052','/0/private/TradeBalance','WkPaViBF7c7BOspUvQymA4Ba/LW/WefuhYTt5DynvVAeivIQpJGSF/kw6kEPkrzTRA40y9iYqO9coWeHefobKQ==')),"base64");
</cfscript>
```

JAVA Function

```
public static String getAuthent(String postData, String nonce, String endpointPath, String secretKeyBase64)
{
        Mac mac512;
        MessageDigest sha256;
        try {
                 SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec 
                       (Base64.decode(secretKeyBase64.getBytes()), HMAC_SHA_512);
                 mac512 = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA_512);
                 mac512.init(secretKey);
                 sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
         } catch (IOException e) {
             ...
         } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
             ...
         } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
             ...
         }
         sha256.update(postData.getBytes());
         sha256.update(nonce.getBytes());
         sha256.update(endpointPath.getBytes());
         mac512.update(sha256.digest());
         return Base64.encodeBytes(mac512.doFinal()).trim();
}
```

Comment: Any relevant code should be in the question itself as text.

Comment: between i added the gist which shows the code i tried in CF and java code

Comment: I know what you did.  That's not the StackOverflow way to do it.  For a start, that gist could disappear at any moment, leaving **future readers** with a question that is essentially meaningless.  If you want our help, you need to ask your questions the right way.  Put the code in the question.  If there is too much code for that, show us just the *relevant* code.

Comment: i did the change

Comment: Please elaborate on `the function is not executing properly`.

Comment: basically the return is not returning me the data

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code in your question. Not in a gist.

Also: The gist is throwing errors and I do not know if this is related to your question.

Anyway: You're calling binaryEncode with the wrong params in your gist. It should be:

`writedump(binaryEncode(getAuthent('nonce=1612466079678052','1612466079678052','/0/private/TradeBalance','WkPaViBF7c7BOspUvQymA4Ba/LW/WefuhYTt5DynvVAeivIQpJGSF/kw6kEPkrzTRA40y9iYqO9coWeHefobKQ=='),"base64"));`

Comment: Thanks, but is my conversion right, i did from java to CF, i did my best to replicate same results but i am not sure